# AJAX request INSERT and UPDATE not working

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, json, mysqli

Can someone let me know why this AJAX Post request is not working. The default listId being sent is 0. savedList consists of ListJSON and ListName. The code is below.

```
$.post('save.php', {"id":listId, "list":JSON.stringify(savedList), 
function(savedListId) {
    listId = savedListId;
    alert('List saved');
    // Refresh to a) get out of edit mode and b) give a bookmarkable URL
    window.location = 'list.html?id='+listId;
});
```

The server side is as belows:

```
if(empty($_POST['list'])) {
header('HTTP/1.0 400 Bad Request', true, 400);
exit('No list sent');
}

if( ! $decodedList = json_decode($_POST['list'])) {
header('HTTP/1.0 400 Bad Request', true, 400);
exit('List does not decode');
}


if(empty($_POST['id']) || $_POST['id']=="null") {
$sql = "INSERT INTO Lists SET ListJSON = ?, ListName = ?";
$query = $mysqli->prepare($sql);
$query->bind_param("ss", $_POST['list'], $decodedList->listName); 
$query->execute();


header('Content-type: application/json');
exit('"'.$mysqli->insert_id.'"');
} else {
$sql = "UPDATE Lists SET ListJSON = ?, ListName = ? WHERE ListID = ?";
$query = $mysqli->prepare($sql);
$query->bind_param("ssi", $_POST['list'], $decodedList->listName, $_POST['id']);

$query->execute();


header('Content-type: application/json');
exit('"'.(int)$_POST['id'].'"');
}
```

Comment: It looks reasonable to me. Add error checking?

Comment: There's a missing right curly-brace in the `$.post` call. Is that just a cut-and-paste error, or in the original code?

Comment: @Barmar ya the curly-brace is a cut and paste error.

Comment: @Barmar could it have something to do with magic quotes being on or off?

Comment: Make sure they're off, magic quotes are an obsolete feature.

Comment: What happens when you try? Specifically what doesn't work about it? Are there any error messages in the log or in your javascript console?

Answer (score 0):

Try adding `(int)` in front of `$_POST['id']`. I believe the javascript is sending id as a string, but you are trying to update it as an int with mysqli.